# How to automate blockchain transactions of users without having to ask them to enter wallet addresses?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, metamask

I am working on a game with an in-game currency.
The goal would be that when a player buys something, he only have to click on buy, without having to enter the public address and so on.

Are smart contracts the solution?
Are there smart contracts implementation platforms available?
Share your ideas and solutions and explain them.

Answer (score 1):

Though your statement is unclear, I'm going to assume the player will be making the purchase using Ether. If a player buys something with Ether, they will need to sign the transaction with the private key of the address containing the Ether they are spending.

The easiest way to do this (to my knowledge) is through Chrome/Brave using MetaMask. If you are planning on developing your game to work in a browser, then this is the best solution you have at the moment.